# CD4026BE Clock not working

Tags: integrated-circuit

I have a CD4026BE Connected as follows. (leds is actually a 7 segment display) When i toggle the clock from pos to neg nothing happens.  IF i keep clock on pos and toggle clock inhabit, it will start counting.  Why does the clock input not work?  I was hoping to use the clock inhabit to stop the counting of the clock input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5gen3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGCqfJ.png)</sup>

*Cleaned-up schematic.*

Comment: What is level on the Inhibit pin when you are applying the clock signal?

Comment: ground.   But i have tried connecting it to pos also while toggling the clock input.

Comment: @user41758: I've cleaned up the schematic and left the original in for comparison. Note how the use of the GND symbol eliminates much wiring and enables instant identification of grounded points in the circuit. (You had omitted a ground connection on your LEDs.) I'll leave it up to you which schematic to leave in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need a pull down resistor on you clock input if your switch is used to pull the clock input high as it is in the schematic.

The data sheet indicates that the counter is advanced on the positive going edge of the clock input.

The data sheet also indicates that the clock inhibit can be used for negative edge counting as you have experienced.

It would also be a good idea to add a small capacitor across the switch to debounce the switch.

Comment: The switch is actually going to be a 555 timer,  for now its just me moving a wire from pos to neg.  Would this be the same as you are saying?

Comment: @user41758 No, you still need a pull-down resistor on your clock input

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHkIjD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. There is some parasitic capacitance on the CMOS inputs.*

CMOS circuits don't like being left floating. They have a very high input impedance and a small capacitance. With your SW1 arrangement the capacitance gets charged to 5 V when the switch is closed. When the switch is opened it will stay at 5 V unless there is enough interference or you have a pull-down resistor.

Pretty much any resistor will pull the input down for you. 100k should do the trick.